# How to make Decibel play in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, sound, gstreamer

[This](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810249) explains why it is not available anymore, but still [its 1.08 version can be installed from deb](http://decibel.silent-blade.org/index.php?n=Main.Download), only it [plays nothing](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/decibel-audio-player/+question/296240).

The idea is that the player is orphaned since 2011 without
an adopter and depends on gstreamer 0.10, which is scheduled for
removal. If installed from deb, it is unable to play any type of file.

Looking for gstreamer 0.10 I have found and installed `gstreamer0.10-nice`, to no effect.

Its future seems grim, but I want to use it as long as I can, because I like the way its file manager can access and manipulate different music directories.

~ In Manjaro it can be easily installed and works great.

Comment: This package says it is built for 16.04 specifically https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/decibel-audio-player/1.06-3 Try it

Comment: @MarkKirby - I have posted all the details in my answer. Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Mark Kirby](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby)'s comment under the question above and to the posts [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=227609#top) (especially post 6), I have found the solution: the needed Decibel package is a **1.06 (not** 1.08) version made for Xenial and available as a deb, which needs as a dependency `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly 0.10` also available as a deb, which instead needs `libx264-146`.

If version 1.08 version is installed, remove it (`sudo apt remove decibel-audio-player`), then, in the following order, download and install, preferably using gdebi-gtk:

- [libx264-146](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libx264-146/2:0.146.2555+git0c21480-1)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly 0.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly/0.10.19-2.1ubuntu3)
- [decibel-audio-player 1.06](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/decibel-audio-player/1.06-3)

Also,`gstreamer0.10-alsa` is needed if not already installed:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer0.10-alsa
```

To be able to add CD play/access to the file manager menu, two optional packages are also needed:

```
sudo apt install cd-discid python-cddb
```